# The image of an Artin representation is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, profinite-groups

First let us define the necessary terms for the problem:

> **Definition**
>
> - Let $G$ be a profinite group and let $k$ be a topological field. An **$n$-dimensional representation** of $G$ over $k$ is a continuous homomorphism of groups $\rho: G \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$.
> - An $n$-dimensional representation of $G$ over $k$ is called an **Artin representation** if $k \subset \mathbb{C}$, i.e. $k$ is a topological subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

**Problem**: Now I would like to show that the **image of an Artin representation is finite**.

**My own progress so far**:

- <s>Since $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{G}$ is a profinite group we know that $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{G}$ is isomorphic to an inverse limit of a projective system of finitely many groups $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\{G_1,\dots,G_m\}}$. In other words,</s>

$$ \require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{ G = \varprojlim_{i} G_i = \left\{ (\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_m) \in \prod_{i=1}^m G_i \: \middle| \: f^j_i(\gamma_j)=\gamma_i \: \forall j \geq i \right\}.}$$

That means that we can insert $m$-tuples $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{ (\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_m) }$ in our presentation $\rho$ which gives us elements $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{ \rho(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_m) \in \operatorname{GL}_n(k) }$.

**Edit**: **I made a huge mistake**! In a projective limit, the groups are finite, not the system of groups! Now I have no idea at all again.

But now I do not know how to continue so solve this problem anymore.

**My specific questions** (besides "*How can I show this statement?*"):

- Why exactly do I need that $k$ is a topological subfield in $\mathbb{C}$?
- How do I handle the group homomorphisms $f^j_i : G_j \to G_i$ in our projective system? Do they play an important role for our problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Ultimately, you need to show that the kernel $K$ of $\rho$ is of finite index in $G$; the first isomorphism theorem then defines an injection of $G/K$ into $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ by $gK \mapsto \rho(g)$, which implies that the image of $\rho$ is finite.

Comment: You need $k$ to be a topological subfield of $\mathbb C$ to make a "no small subgroup argument" in order to argue that $K$ is *open* (which immediately implies it is of finite index, since $G$ is compact).

Comment: The specific group homomorphisms $f_i^j$ are not really important.  The important things about $G$ are its properties as a topological group.

Answer (score 5):

This comes down to the "no small subgroup argument."

**Lemma**: Let $H = \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$, where $k$ is a topological subfield of $\mathbb C$.  There exists an open neighborhood $U$ of the identity matrix $I$ which contains no subgroups of $H$ besides the trivial subgroup.

A consequence of the lemma is that if $\rho: G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ is a continuous homomorphism, then the kernel of $\rho$ is an *open* subgroup of $G$.  Since $G$ is profinite, it is compact, so the kernel of $\rho$ is of finite index in $G$.  This immediately implies that the image of $\rho$ is finite.

To see that the kernel of $\rho$ is open, take an open neighborhood $U$ as in the lemma, and consider the preimage $\rho^{-1}(U)$, which is an open neighborhood of $1_G$.  It's a general fact about profinite groups that inside any open neighborhood of the identity, you can find an open subgroup.  So let $N$ be an open subgroup of $G$ contained in $\rho^{-1}(U)$.  Then $\rho(N)$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ which is contained in $U$.  By the hypothesis on $U$, $\rho(N)$ must be the trivial group, i.e. $N$ must be contained in $\operatorname{Ker}\rho$.  Thus $\operatorname{Ker} \rho$ contains an open subgroup, so it is itself open.

*Proof of the lemma*: It suffices to prove the lemma in the case $k = \mathbb C$, since if $U$ is an open neighborhood of $I$ which works for $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$, then $U \cap \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ is one which works for $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$.

The case $n =1$ (where you are working with $\operatorname{GL}_1(\mathbb C) = \mathbb C^{\ast}$) is obvious.

For arbitrary $n$, I have seen several proofs of this.  My [favorite](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103783/no-small-subgroups-argument) one comes from differential geometry.  The same link provides alternative proofs.